# Flutter Bottom Container Swipe Up

Tags: flutter, maps, google-places-api

I'm making an app which shows place detail when clicking a place on Google Maps. I can open a container at bottom of the page but I want to do that when the user swipe this container to up with animation, the container will cover the whole page and I will get extra information about that place and show the user.
How can I do that with Flutter?

[image: Bottom Container]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try to use the package here:

https://pub.dev/packages/sliding_up_panel

However, if this does not fullfill you wish, try this instead: Wrap you Widget with a GestureDetector and an AnimatedController:

```
double containerHeight = 0;
GestureDetector(
  onVerticalDragEnd: (dragUpdateDetails) {
    setState(){
       containerHeight = //device height or use MediaQuery.of(context).size.height//
    }
  },
  child: AnimatedContainer(
         duration: Duration(milliseconds: //how long should it take//), 
         height: containerHeight,
         child: //whatever you want//
   )
),
```

AnimatedController automatically animates between changes of properties. However, you might want to try changing **onVertivalDragEnd** to something else like **onVerticalDragUpdate** to fullfill your wish completely. If you want to have that behaviour for the full screen, wrap your first return Widget with the GestureDetector.

Answer (score 1):

I guess `DragableScrollableSheet` fits your need. There is a good explanation [here](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/DraggableScrollableSheet-class.html) in the documentation.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `DraggableScrollableSheet`

Document and Video tutorial available here:
https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/DraggableScrollableSheet-class.html